# Kubernetes (docker) access to Kafka in docker compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, docker-compose, microservices

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes: 
      - ./data/zoo/zk-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./data/zoo/zk-txn-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.0.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes: 
      - ./data/kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.0.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
```

dev.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-server
  labels:
    app: auth-server
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8882
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8882
      nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    app: auth-server
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - hostname: localhost
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-server
spec:
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: auth-server
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-server
          image: auth-server:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: auth-server
              mountPath: "/config"
      volumes:
        - name: auth-server
          configMap:
            name: auth-server
```

I need connect from my app on kubernetes cluser (docker) connect to docker-compose kafka.
I tried change kafka url in properties: http://localhost:9092, http://broker:9092 and
[THIS](https://blog.knoldus.com/how-to-use-external-kafka-from-kubernetes/) tutorial but won't work too.

In **docker ps** I see: kafka and auth-server from kubernetes.

Can someone explain me. How can I do it ?

Comment: are the cluster and the docker-compose running in the same VM/server ?

Comment: Why do you mix the concepts? you could convert the docker-compose to kubernetes setup as well, for example.

Comment: I suggest looking into https://strimzi.io or the Confluent Helm Charts, but the short answer is that these services are going to need to be on the same network, and seeing that the Compose file has no network mentioned, then they are not

Comment: Thomas hmm In docker compose I have volume on desktop, I need this. Can I do it in k8s?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know your flavor of local K8s, I can only speculate. But the problem here could be that Kubernetes and docker compose run their containers in different virtual networks.

What you have to do to create connectivity is:

1. Expose the Kafka port in your compose file with port mappings to the host:

   ```
   ports:
   - 9092:9092
   ```
2. Connect to it from Kubernetes via the IP address of your docker0 interface (typically 172.17.0.1).

Comment: I have exposed. Where can I connect from Kubernetes to localhost?

Comment: Try pointing the kafka url of your Pod to 172.17.0.1:9092